# NodeJS inspect 0.0.0.0 not hitting breakpoints

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, nginx, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector

I'm on Ubuntu 16 on a droplet on Digital Ocean, installed nodejs and am trying to remote debug.

I have nginx proxying port 80 traffic to the localhost:3000 app and all works well when I access the droplets IP.

I start the app like so

```
node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 app.js
```

I get a message like this.

```
Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/5f583ab2-4ebf-4f73-84de-01500c38d31f
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
✓ App is running at http://localhost:3000 in development mode
   Press CTRL-C to stop
```

In Chrome I have the NiM setup on my host and port.

The window opens automatically whenever I start the app, but that's when the fun stops.

No breakpoints are being hit and no logging is happening in the dev tools console and every few minutes it says "disconnected" and I have to hit reconnect. Is --inspect not built to be remote debugged like this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the chrome plugin Node Inspector Manager that was the issue. Not anything else to do with nodejs itself. Once I visited chrome:://inspect , added the remote host of domain:port, it popped up to inspect when I started the process and I clicked "Open Dedicated Devtools for Node" and voila alls well in the debugging world.